# SQL Transaction with call to external API

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I would to know what do you think about this situation. I am making a call to external API rest service in behalf of the customer and I need to save to record for that action and I want to be sure that the record is saved (or update) only if the external API action was successful But if the API was successful the recorded MUST be saved. Although I did not use it I know there is solution for that in the concept of SQL transaction that make sure that entire transaction is saved or none of it. But what if part of the transaction is calling to external API such as credit card API or bank account. Can you refer me to some documentation about that?

I actually have close connection to the people who are creating the API and can ask them to change the response or to do something special if needed.

Here is a Use Case (Shoes Store):

User in our website want to buy shoes. He writing his credit card number in the form and click submit. We are making two actions than:

1. API call to the credit card provider
2. Inserting a row in our DB after the the API call with the response with credit card Provider

Both actions has a possibility of failure. I am not sure about how I should order of those actions. And if insert the row only after the API call how can I make sure that at least I have knowledge that something went wrong in inserting the line? Because I do not want a situation where the user get charged for something in his credit card and I do not have a record for that

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I know this general question but I really do not have any leads. I edit it a little bit, maybe it will help

Comment: It is still very broad. Typically the API provider supplies a set of instructions you should use to implement their processes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my temporary solution please tell me what you think about it.
It is made from six steps and each step depends on the previous one. It based on an extra column called payment_successful that is 0 or 1. When inserting the row it set to 0 and after the credit card provider API return a successful transaction response it is update to 1. To make sure that all the DB call are successful I check it with select after each change. I will demonstrate it with my shoe purchase with credit card example. Let say the user click on confirm show purchase button:

1. Insert a row into the purchase table (catalogue_id=132, price=500$, cerdit_card_number=8988123456, payment_successful=0) and get back the purchase_id PK
2. Select the row from the table by purchase_id (of previous insert). This makes sure that the row was inserted successfully. otherwise alert (by email) that something is wrong
3. Make the Credit Card API Provider call (result = curl(http://api.american-express.com/?credit_card_number=8988123456))
4. Checking the result from the credit card API check if it successful (if(result===1)) otherwise alert that something is wrong
5. Updating the row by purchase_id setting payment_successful = 1
6. Select the row from the table by purchase_id and checking that row.payment_successful == 1. otherwise alert that something is wrong

Of curse all the URLs above are not real